# Can I delete the repository and create a new one named the same to resolve the problem when GitHub LFS quota exceeds?

Tags: github, git-lfs

As the title describes, I did so but the problem remains with the log:

`batch response: This repository is over its data quota. Account responsible for LFS bandwidth should purchase more data packs to restore access.`

So is there a way that works? I don't need to retain the history of the repository or any contents within it, since it is only used to store & publish on-line built binaries. Purchasing more data packs and bandwidth is not an option for me either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub's Git LFS quota is per-user account.  It resets once a month, and then you get another free gigabyte of download.  It doesn't matter how many repositories you have, and deleting them doesn't help.

In general, Git repositories, whether using Git LFS or not, are not a good fit for storing binaries.  If you're using a GitHub repository, you can use release assets for binaries built from your repository, which are available without charge.  If you're just trying to upload and distribute binaries, a different approach would be warranted, such as a VPS with a web server or a cloud bucket.

Comment: OK, that's helpful. Also I note these words you say: "If you're using a GitHub repository, you can use release assets for binaries built from your repository, which are available without charge. " I had tried to do so and wrote an action file containing buid step with trigger condition "release" and found no built binaries within the assets of the output, so can you tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: Or to say how I should write the action file to manage this?

Comment: That is a different question and should be asked separately.  You'll need to use the REST API to create a release and then upload assets to it.  You can see how Git LFS does this [in their release script](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/script/upload).